# Unable to start jack server ? Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).

Tags: jack

Im trying to start jackd using QJackCtl but it fails with error messages
 Here is what I'm seeing -

```
14:36:48.194 Patchbay deactivated.
    14:36:48.198 Statistics reset.
    14:36:48.228 ALSA connection change.
    14:36:48.241 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
    Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
    Cannot connect to server socket
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    Registered event listener change listener:  true 
    14:36:48.258 ALSA connection graph change.
    14:37:12.679 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
    Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
    Cannot connect to server socket
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "2"  obj:  QMessageBox(0xbfd7c2d0) "" 
    FIXME: handle dialog start. 
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: Starting jack server...
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot lock down 82241434 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)[0m
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: control device hw:0
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: control device hw:0
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : Cannot allocate memory[0m
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...[0m
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot initialize driver[0m
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: [1m[31mERROR: JackServer::Open() failed with -1[0m
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:12 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to open server[0m
    Sat Feb  2 14:37:13 2013: Saving settings to "/home/soham/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
    FIXME: handle dialog end. 
    14:37:17.923 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
    Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
    Cannot connect to server socket
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "2"  obj:  QMessageBox(0xbfd7cb40) "" 
    FIXME: handle dialog start. 
    FIXME: handle dialog end. 
    QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "6"  obj:  QMenu(0x8d0f0a0) ""
```

**Note : If I restart my machine "Jack" start working again until I play something, like movies or songs etc using vlc or any other media player.**

Answer (score 5):

I am new but I will try to answer your question. It sounds like you may be going through something similar to my own ordeal. Try this in the terminal. Here is the code.

```
pulseaudio --kill
jack_control  start.
```

Then when you are done with jack do this. Here is the code.

```
jack_control exit
pulseaudio --start.
```

I hope this helps.